# Using the in operator for all javascript types

Tags: javascript

What would be the correct way to do the following for each type in javascript:

```
// string
"h" in "hello"

// array
"hello" in ["hello", "abc", "yes"]

// obj
"hello" in {"hello": "new"}
```

I'd like to get a boolean returned for each of the above iterables. I know the `obj` works fine as-is, but what would be the simplest way for all the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both strings and arrays, use `.includes`:

```js
console.log('hello'.includes('h'));
console.log(["hello", "abc", "yes"].includes('hello'));
```

Note that `.includes` is ES6, so include a polyfill to support older browsers as well: [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill) [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill)